# Проблема с входом в phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Установлен сервер Apache (C:\Program Files\Apache2.2),  PHP (C:\Program Files\PHP ),  MySQL (C:\Program Files\MySQL). Создана папка C:\www\phpmyadmin. Файл конфига **config.inc.php**

```
<?php      
$i = 0;
$i++;      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';      
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root'; // Пароль пользователя root    
?>
```

Попытка зайти выдает такую ошибку

[image]

Зайти в базу через консоль не получается

[image]

При этом при установке был выбран пользователь root с паролем root. В чем заключается проблема?

Answer (score 1):

У root просто нет пароля. Логин root , пароль пустое поле.

Answer (score 0):

У вас пароль на рута не root
попробуйте его восстановить [Password](http://www.youisbee.ru/howto/mysql/66-ustanovka-izmenenie-i-sbros-parolya-root-v-mysql.html)